# Reduce daily status table to only contain status changes

Tags: python, mysql, csv, terminal

I have a large (570m rows) daily status table for 100k+ users. Currently it is in MySQL (or CSV). The table contains three columns: user_id, status, and date. Ideally, I'd like to reduce the table to a new table that includes user_id, status, start_date, end_date for each status period (where a period is at least one date).

The challenge is that users can switch back and forth between status: I cannot assume that a period is defined as the difference between min and max date for a given status.

I can work with a solution in MySQL, Python or using the terminal (mac).

Current data:

```
user_id, status, date
1, GRE, 2018-09-02
1, GRE, 2018-09-03
1, PRO, 2018-09-04
1, PRO, 2018-09-05
1, PRO, 2018-09-06
1, GRE, 2018-09-07
1, GRE, 2018-09-08
1, GRE, 2018-09-09
1, GRE, 2018-09-10
```

Desired new format:

```
user_id, status, start_date, end_date
1, GRE, 2018-09-02, 2018-09-03
1, PRO, 2018-09-04, 2018-09-06
1, GRE, 2018-09-07, 2018-09-10
```

Comment: I use version 8.0.15

Comment: There is no unique primary key. After loading the CSV file (from external source) I have only added an index on user_id. I can add a unique index column to the CSV and reload the data if your solution requires it.

Comment: At this point it's a combination of date and user_id (exactly one record per user per day - from each user's start date).

Comment: All of these people took time to try to help you. I think it's weird not to acknowledge their efforts in some way.

Comment: I don't disagree and am very grateful for the time and effort by all. I just thought it was best practice to avoid "non-relevant" comments. For the record, I went with the MySQL solution you provided because it was easier for me to implement (although the query took many hours to run). I am sure the Python suggestions would have worked as well.

Comment: I'm unaware of best practice, only common courtesy. And besides, I'm sure the ability to 'upvote' was provided for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

Schema

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(user_id INT NOT NULL
,status CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1, 'GRE', '2018-09-02'),
(1, 'GRE', '2018-09-03'),
(1, 'PRO', '2018-09-04'),
(1, 'PRO', '2018-09-05'),
(1, 'PRO', '2018-09-06'),
(1, 'GRE', '2018-09-07'),
(1, 'GRE', '2018-09-08'),
(1, 'GRE', '2018-09-09'),
(1, 'GRE', '2018-09-10'),

(2, 'GRE', '2018-09-02'),
(2, 'GRE', '2018-09-03'),
(2, 'PRO', '2018-09-04'),
(2, 'PRO', '2018-09-05'),
(2, 'PRO', '2018-09-06'),
(2, 'GRE', '2018-09-07'),
(2, 'GRE', '2018-09-08'),
(2, 'GRE', '2018-09-09'),
(2, 'GRE', '2018-09-10');
```

Query

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT user_id
       , status
       , date
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) 
       - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id,status ORDER BY DATE) grp
    FROM my_table
    )
SELECT t.user_id
     , t.status
     , MIN(t.date) start
     , MAX(t.date) finish
  FROM t
 GROUP  
    BY user_id
     , status
     , grp
 ORDER  
    BY user_id
     , start;
     

+---------+--------+------------+------------+
| user_id | status | start      | finish     |
+---------+--------+------------+------------+
|       1 | GRE    | 2018-09-02 | 2018-09-03 |
|       1 | PRO    | 2018-09-04 | 2018-09-06 |
|       1 | GRE    | 2018-09-07 | 2018-09-10 |
|       2 | GRE    | 2018-09-02 | 2018-09-03 |
|       2 | PRO    | 2018-09-04 | 2018-09-06 |
|       2 | GRE    | 2018-09-07 | 2018-09-10 |
+---------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First we will need to add another column to your dataframe to distinguish between 'GRE' status in the beginning and end of your dataframe (and similarly other repeating statuses). In other words, need to track when the statuses change.

```
df['track_id'] = (df.status.shift() != df.status).cumsum()
```

df:

```
   user_id status        date  track_id
0        1    GRE  2018-09-02         1
1        1    GRE  2018-09-03         1
2        1    PRO  2018-09-04         2
3        1    PRO  2018-09-05         2
4        1    PRO  2018-09-06         2
5        1    GRE  2018-09-07         3
6        1    GRE  2018-09-08         3
7        1    GRE  2018-09-09         3
8        1    GRE  2018-09-10         3
```

Then, for each combination of `status,track_id` take out the first and last rows using `groupby()`

```
df_f = df.groupby(['status','track_id']).first().reset_index()
df_l = df.groupby(['status','track_id']).last().reset_index()
```

df_f:

```
  status  track_id  user_id        date
0    GRE         1        1  2018-09-02
1    GRE         3        1  2018-09-07
2    PRO         2        1  2018-09-04
```

df_l:

```
  status  track_id  user_id        date
0    GRE         1        1  2018-09-03
1    GRE         3        1  2018-09-10
2    PRO         2        1  2018-09-06
```

Rename the `date` column in `df_f` and `df_l` to `start_date` and `end_date` respectively:

```
df_f.rename(columns = {'date':'start_date'}, inplace=True)
df_l.rename(columns = {'date':'end_date'}, inplace=True)
```

Finally merge both the dataframes to get your desired format:

```
final_df = df_f.merge(df_l, on=['status','track_id','user_id'])
```

final_df:

```
final_df.sort_values('track_id')
  status  track_id  user_id  start_date    end_date
0    GRE         1        1  2018-09-02  2018-09-03
2    PRO         2        1  2018-09-04  2018-09-06
1    GRE         3        1  2018-09-07  2018-09-10
```

Note that I did the whole operation for `user_id = 1`  only to give you an idea. For more user_ids, you will need to filter them out first, apply above operation individually on them, and then concat in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

def format_data(filenm):
    # Load CSV to Dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv(filenm, skipinitialspace=True)
    
    # Add a column that allows grouping consecutive rows with same status
    #  (note: technique from https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-dataframe-group-by-consecutive-same-values-128913875dba)
    df['same'] = (df['status'] != df['status'].shift()).cumsum()
    
    # Get dates fro grouped user id and rows with same status
    g = df.groupby(['user_id', 'same'])['date']
    
    # Add start and stop dates based upon above grouping
    df = df.assign(startdate = g.transform('first'), enddate = g.transform('last'))
    
    # Return Dataframe with userid, status, startdate, enddate
    return df.groupby(['user_id', 'same']).agg({
        'status': 'first',                     # use first item in group
        'startdate': 'first',                  # use first item in group
        'enddate': 'last'                      # use last item in group
    }).reset_index().drop('same', 1)         # Drop 'same' column (only used for grouping)
```

**Usage**

```
result = format_data('myfile.txt')
```

*Input* myfile.txt

(Added a second user id to OP data for demonstration)

```
user_id, status, date
1, GRE, 2018-09-02
1, GRE, 2018-09-03
1, PRO, 2018-09-04
1, PRO, 2018-09-05
1, PRO, 2018-09-06
1, GRE, 2018-09-07
1, GRE, 2018-09-08
1, GRE, 2018-09-09
1, GRE, 2018-09-10
2, GRE, 2018-09-08
2, GRE, 2018-09-09
2, PRO, 2018-09-10
```

*Result*

```
    user_id status  startdate   enddate
0   1   GRE 2018-09-02  2018-09-03
1   1   PRO 2018-09-04  2018-09-06
2   1   GRE 2018-09-07  2018-09-10
3   2   GRE 2018-09-08  2018-09-09
4   2   PRO 2018-09-10  2018-09-10
```