# automating account updates - Windows function Problem - MYSQL / SNOWFLAKE

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, snowflake-schema

I have two tables that contains account and owners.

Table 1 / CASE 1:

```
create table table_acc( acc int, owner_id  int, start_date date,  end_date date);

insert into table_acc values (    1,         101,            '2021-01-01',         '2021-02-28');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-03-01',         '2021-04-30');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-03-01',         '2021-04-30');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-04-30',         '2021-05-30');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-05-01',         '2021-06-30');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         103,            '2021-07-01',         '2021-08-30');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-09-01',         '2021-10-30');
```

Table 2 / CASE 2:

```
    create table table_acc( acc int, owner_id  int, start_date date,  end_date date);
    
insert into table_acc values (    1,         101,            '2021-05-10 ',        '2021-05-10');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-05-10',         '2021-05-14');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         101,            '2021-05-14',         '2100-01-01');
```

I am trying to get the dates of the owners for their accounts, if the owner is the same for some consecutive rows then I would like to have one row with the first start date and the latest end date.
however, if the same owner appears after an additional owner then this time the owner should not be considered as old owner and hence it must have its own end date

similarly if for one account there is only one owner with multiple entries then it should give the end date as the recent one

The Expected output for TABLE 1 / case 1:

```
acc ownerid     start date   end date
1   101        2021-01-01   2021-02-28
1   102        2021-03-01   2021-06-30
1   103        2021-07-01   2021-08-30
1   102        2021-09-01   2021-10-30
```

The Expected output for TABLE 2/ case 2:

```
acc     owner id             start             end date        
1         101            2021-05-10         2021-05-10      
1         102            2021-05-10         2021-05-19       
1         101            2021-05-19         2022-01-01
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
select 
acc,
owner_id,
min(start_date),
max(end_date)
from (
select *,
(dense_rank() over (partition by acc order by start_date))-
(dense_rank() over (partition by acc,owner_id order by start_date)) rank_ from table_acc
) t
group by 1,2, rank_
order by 1,3
```

The code gives the correct output for table 1 / case 1 but not for the table 2 / case 2. Here for more details:

Case 1:[Case 1 Table and Results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=897589554e264da338f939cf7fb52c7a)

Case 2: [Case 2 Table and Results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=141e3ae1645739be6000c9626d6ac14f)

Comment: Seems rather similar to this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553864/reduce-daily-status-table-to-only-contain-status-changes/67558590#67558590

Comment: @Strawberry its a bit different than my solution here, can you point me to the right direction in my code here ?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: it is same problem as mentioned by @strawberry. There is no difference except you are storing end date in different column.

Comment: @akhilesh somehow it is not working. would appreciate if you guys can help me with that

Comment: @Strawberry with your code for the following case the code doest return the correct output acc: 1 id: owner id : 1 start date: 2021-05-10 end date: 2021-05-10, acc:1 owner id : 2 start date: 2021-05-10 end date: 2021-05-14 , id: 1 , owner id : 1, start date: 2021-05-14, end_date : 2021-10-01         I expect it to return three rows but it is giving 2 rows 1: owner id :1, start date 2021-05-10 and end date = 2021-10-01   and for owner id : 2 , start date: 2021-05-10 , end date: 2021-05-14

Comment: I can only refer you to previous comments

Comment: @Strawberry https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99ca12c51278819a7f69d4fa8552d11a maybe this will help to understand the issue

Comment: The data sets appear to be different.

Comment: @Strawberry yes that is one case that i have found is not working, ideally, it should give the correct output with both data sets

Comment: @trillion can you explain table2 and its output

Comment: @ Akhilesh I would like to have the same results as for the table 1 but with the table 2 data it is not working. I would expect the results to show owner 1 twice as he didn't appear simultaneously in the table. [ there was another owner i.e owner 2 who took care of his account]. In this case then the owner 1 should appear with another start and end date. The expected output and the table values are added in the question

Answer (score 1):

Based on @strawberry's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553864/reduce-daily-status-table-to-only-contain-status-changes/67558590#67558590)

this will the solution

```
select 
acc,
owner_id,
min(start_date),
max(end_date)
from (
select *,
(dense_rank() over (partition by acc order by start_date))-
(dense_rank() over (partition by acc,owner_id order by start_date)) rank_ from table_acc
) t
group by 1,2, rank_
order by 1,3
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=897589554e264da338f939cf7fb52c7a)

EDIT:
If you have multiple groups having same `start_date` then above solution will not work: try this one:

```
select acc,owner_id,min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (
select acc,owner_id,start_date,end_date,
sum(col1) over (partition by acc order by start_date,owner_id) grp  from (
select 
*,case when owner_id=lag(owner_id,1) over(partition by acc order by start_date) then 0 else 1 end col1
from table_acc) tab
) t
group by 1,2, grp
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=245d8cee1d6ef835c41c1c52d17ba356)

Comment: with your code for the following case the code doest return the correct output acc: 1 id: owner id : 1 start date: 2021-05-10 end date: 2021-05-10, acc:1 owner id : 2 start date: 2021-05-10 end date: 2021-05-14 , id: 1 , owner id : 1, start date: 2021-05-14, end_date : 2021-10-01 I expect it to return three rows but it is giving 2 rows 1: owner id :1, start date 2021-05-10 and end date = 2021-10-01 and for owner id : 2 , start date: 2021-05-10 , end date: 2021-05-14

Comment: This is different dataset. Can you post the data in fiddle format. so that we can check the problem. as per your example in question it is working fine.

Comment: sure, it works with the above cases but not for this one which is similar. Here is the link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99ca12c51278819a7f69d4fa8552d11a

Comment: I have edited the questions so you can now better understand the issue

Comment: In table 2 the owner changed from owner 1 to owner 2 and then back to owner 1. If it is the case that there are multiple rows with the same owner simultaneously [like in table 1] then the maximum should return. But if the same owner appears later in time after the account is passed to some second owner: owner 2 , then new start and end date should reflect instead of a MAX() on the overall appearance of owner 1

Comment: sorry for the confusion I just fixed it

Comment: the questions is the same it should return 3 rows in total 2 for owner 1 and  one row for the owner 2. which is not the case https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=141e3ae1645739be6000c9626d6ac14f

Comment: did you check ?

Comment: it doesn't work please check this fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8aaea677d2a244c056df4eca45a0a340 . The solution should cover both cases as for some owner there could be owners with same start dates

Comment: Case 1 [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac6a4816bae7fd200a8f0b17ea4462b8)  and Case 2 [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=245d8cee1d6ef835c41c1c52d17ba356) with new solution. for first case I have added the both solution. Please check and tell me the exact difference.

Comment: I think it is working. These cases are in reality not separate and all of those rows belong to one table. Hence the solution should be dynamic which can handle both case 1 and case 2. Can you please confirm if that is the case? Also would really appreciate if you can explain the final code [second one] ?