# Select Row w/ Value Y after Row w/ Value X & Efficiency

Tags: mysql

- MySQL 8.0.25 (using mainly HeidiSQL, but also Command Line at times)
- Windows 10 (dedicated MySQL machine)
- 128GB Ram
- Separate SSD for both OS and Data Drives
- Temp DIR pointing to Data Drive w/ 600GB free space
- 82Mil+ rows of data I'm querying, about 18GB in size

**WHAT I HAVE**

| ID | signal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | x |
| 3 | y |
| 4 | x |
| 5 | y |
| 6 | y |
| 7 | y |
| 8 | x |
| 9 | y |
| 10 | x |
| 11 | y |

**WHAT I NEED**

| X ID | Y ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 |

**EXPLANATION:**

Basically, I have a list of variables (X and Y) in a single column. I need to find X and then the following row with Y after the row with X. However, sometimes, as seen in the example above, there's multiple X's and Y's repeated after each other (ie- row 1 & 2). I need the FIRST X and then the FIRST Y following that one (and skip the row with the repeated X).

The next X chosen would be AFTER the Y from the previously used row. ie- The X for Row ID 4 would be the next one after the 1st results row, and X in Row ID 2 would never be used.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT
    x_tbl.id,
    (
        SELECT
            y_tbl.id
        FROM
            t_table AS y_tbl
        WHERE
            signal = "y"
            AND
            MIN(y_tbl.id) > x_tbl.id
        LIMIT
            1
    ) y_id
FROM
    t_table AS x_tbl
WHERE
    x_tbl.signal = "x"
```

The problem is InnoDB rescans the entire DB for every. single. row. My REAL code is pulling the data together from the original tables, and then thru some CTE's to filter down the amount of data before getting to this step (things like data, etc). From my tests that really helps to speed things up- but- running this across the entire DB literally takes 10+ days to complete. It's insane.

Is there a more efficient way to write this?

Comment: How about something along these lines... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553864/reduce-daily-status-table-to-only-contain-status-changes/67558590#67558590

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm about 75% there on understanding your example- but- not totally sure why, in the 'grp' field, you're subtracting one Dense Rank (user id) and a combo Dense Rank (user ID, Status). Can you explain how/why that's done? I suspect it has something to do with putting the 'newest' status change at a higher/lower rank- but not entirely sure...

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PS7gV64j1gkXdbvgtPKC8/0 for a bit of a break down... Here we were interested in status changes. These occur whenever the result of x minus y differs from the result in the 'previous' row.

Comment: This is brilliant, btw. However, what if I wanted to INCLUDE the date of the status change itself (ie- in your example, instead of the start & finish date being of the same status, I'd want the start date of the first status, and then the date of the 'changed' status itself as the finish date)? Would I use some sort of adding 1 to the finish date row, or perhaps a LEAD(MIN(date)) type thing? Just to clarify- the output I want would be:
|       1 | GRE    | 2018-09-02 | 2018-09-04 |
|       1 | PRO    | 2018-09-04 | 2018-09-07 |
Thank you!

Comment: This sounds different enough to warrant a question in its own right. The good news is, you now have the tools at your disposal to ask that question.

Comment: New Question posted [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876852/selecting-every-other-row-transposing-dense-rank-efficiency) Thank you @Strawberry !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

A thought...

1. Use `LEAD()` (or `LAG()`) to filter out rows with dup `signals`.
2. Add a new `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.  This is to get row numbers.  (I don't know of this old trick is faster or slower than using `ROW_NUMBER()`.)
3. Do a self-join to pair up even/odd rows based on the new row numbers.