# Selecting Every Other Row & Transposing: Dense Rank, Efficiency?

Tags: mysql, performance, transpose, dense-rank

**WHAT I HAVE (data generated from a query below):**

```
| ID     | IND | SIG | START               |
|--------|-----|----:|---------------------|
| 1      | atr |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:05:00 |
| 2      | atr |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:16:00 |
| 3      | atr |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:17:00 |
| 4      | atr |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:26:00 |
| 5      | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:07:00 |
| 6      | ema |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:09:00 |
| 7      | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:10:00 |
| 8      | ema |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:18:00 |
| 9      | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:20:00 |
| 10     | ema |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:27:00 |
| 11     | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:29:00 |
| 12     | tig |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:12:00 |
| 13     | tig |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:13:00 |
| 14     | tig |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:14:00 |
| 15     | tig |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:15:00 |
| 16     | tig |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:23:00 |
| 17     | tig |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:28:00 |
```

**WHAT I NEED:**

```
| IND | START ID | START SIG | START DT            | END ID | END SIG | END DT              |
|-----|----------|----------:|---------------------|--------|---------|---------------------|
| atr | 1        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:05:00 | 2      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:16:00 |
| atr | 3        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:17:00 | 4      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:26:00 |
| ema | 6        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:09:00 | 7      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:10:00 |
| ema | 8        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:18:00 | 9      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:20:00 |
| ema | 10       |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:27:00 | 11     | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:29:00 |
| tig | 13       |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:13:00 | 14     | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:14:00 |
| tig | 15       |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:15:00 | 16     | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:23:00 |
```

**DETAILS:**

I need help (transposing?) every other row of generated data from a     query (thanks @Strawberry!) Basically for every id where SIG = 1 with    the same IND, I need the earliest ID/DATE where SIG = 3.

Each IND grouping and the start/finish combo must start with SIG = 1,    and FINISH w/ SIG = 3 within the same row.

Missing ID's #5, 12, 17 are due to not following the above point (ie- the grouping might have started with 3 as the earliest date, or     ended on a 1 so those rows are eliminated from the results).

Data is over 800+mil rows, so the query needs to be efficient. I'm not sure if the original query can be re-written to reflect what's needed, or, if I keep the original query and add to it to manipulate the output into the new format?

**CURRENT QUERY & DATA:**

[FIDDLE LINK](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f31HrAKzpuiF77Ed8R1iSH/0)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ind CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,SIG TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
,dt DATETIME NOT NULL
,price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(ind,dt)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('atr', 1, '2018/09/04 11:05:00', 10),
('atr', 1, '2018/09/04 11:06:00', 15),
('ema', 3, '2018/09/04 11:07:00', 12),
('atr', 1, '2018/09/04 11:08:00', 98),
('ema', 1, '2018/09/04 11:09:00', 14),
('ema', 3, '2018/09/04 11:10:00', 17),
('ema', 3, '2018/09/04 11:11:00', 72),
('tig', 3, '2018/09/04 11:12:00', 63),
('tig', 1, '2018/09/04 11:13:00', 33),
('tig', 3, '2018/09/04 11:14:00', 53),
('tig', 1, '2018/09/04 11:15:00', 58),
('atr', 3, '2018/09/04 11:16:00', 954),
('atr', 1, '2018/09/04 11:17:00', 2),
('ema', 1, '2018/09/04 11:18:00', 8),
('ema', 1, '2018/09/04 11:19:00', 9),
('ema', 3, '2018/09/04 11:20:00', 95),
('ema', 3, '2018/09/04 11:21:00', 75),
('tig', 1, '2018/09/04 11:22:00', 25),
('tig', 3, '2018/09/04 11:23:00', 60),
('atr', 1, '2018/09/04 11:24:00', 3),
('tig', 3, '2018/09/04 11:25:00', 18),
('atr', 3, '2018/09/04 11:26:00', 94),
('ema', 1, '2018/09/04 11:27:00', 42),
('tig', 1, '2018/09/04 11:28:00', 35),
('ema', 3, '2018/09/04 11:29:00', 7);

WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT
          IND,
          SIG,
          DT,
          (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY IND ORDER BY DT) 
              - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY IND, SIG ORDER BY DT)) GRP
        FROM
            my_table
        ORDER BY
            IND,
            DT,
            SIG
    )
SELECT
    IND,
    SIG,
    MIN(DT) START
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    IND,
    SIG,
    GRP
ORDER BY
    IND,
    START
;
```

Comment: Check out [gaps-and-islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands%2bmysql?tab=Frequent) tagged questions for MySQL database, please.

Comment: Please specify how "every other" can be derived from the available columns, _not_ the order in the table.  Then we can help you further.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question- I explained it in the OP... Each grouping needs to start with the SIG = 1 as the Start, and End with the earliest row after that one where Sig = 3. Does that help explain at all? If not please ask and I'll try to clarify ASAP!

Comment: Also- the dataset is not a continuous, sequential set. As per the query use to generate the data, there can be gaps between...